# Java parsing mentions from tweet

Tags: java, regex, twitter

i'm trying to parse username mentions from specific tweet using regex, but it always returns **IllegalStateException** that match is not found but i know that regex is good as it works for others http://shahmirj.com/blog/extracting-twitter-usertags-using-regex found it on this site.

```
    String input = "@rivest talk in 30 minutes #hype";
    String regex = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\\\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Could you help me to find mistake here ? Or should I used different regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `find()`, which is one of the matching methods, as documented in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
String input = "@rivest talk in 30 minutes #hype";
String regex = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\\\.]))@([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

I also did a small tweak on the regex, as the `+` after `[A-Za-z]` seemed pointless.

Answer (score 0):

From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> The explicit state of a matcher is initially undefined; attempting to
>   query any part of it before a successful match will cause an
>   IllegalStateException to be thrown. The explicit state of a matcher is
>   recomputed by every match operation.

You have to call `matcher.matches()` before calling `matcher.group(0)`